# 5mm margin is not 5mm?

Tags: geometry, crop, cropmarks

I'm using package `geometry` and `crop` in order to print a paper in a professional printer. I set in the `geometry` package an internal margin of 5mm, and in `crop` I use an external 5mm margin. So I'd expect that the two margins are equals... Let's look at the output pdf:

[image]

Apparently they are not equal... Why ? How could I correct that ?

Thank you !

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=297truemm,paperheight=210truemm,margin=5mm,nohead,nofoot,nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[width=302truemm,height=215truemm,center,pdftex,frame,noinfo]{crop}

\begin{document}
This frame goes out of this document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you print from within Acrobat Reader? Make sure that document scaling/centering and the like is set to **None** in the Print dialogue.

Comment: @AlexG : No, I tried it on Okular and Evince, two linux pdf render, both of them have the same output, and in the property document they display the good size. I can't find anything related to scaling and/or centering in these programs.

Comment: In my Evince print dialogue, there is a Tab "PageHandling", which presents several options (Page Scaling, Auto Rotate and Center). But this may be system or spooler dependent (I am using Cups). If you have Cups too, make sure the correct printer driver (specific PPD file for your printer model) is used.

Comment: Well, you seem to be wanting that 2.5mm equal 5mm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add 10mm to both dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  showframe,
  paperwidth=297mm,
  paperheight=210mm,
  margin=5mm,
  nohead,
  nofoot,
  nomarginpar,
  pdftex=false,dvips=false,vtex=false,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  width=307mm,
  height=220mm,
  center,
  pdftex,
  frame,
  noinfo
]{crop}

\begin{document}
This frame goes out of this document.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `true` is not necessary; the `crop` package recommends disabling `geometry` drivers.

You get the same result with `geometry` only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  showframe,showcrop,
  paperwidth=307mm,
  paperheight=220mm,
  layoutwidth=297mm,
  layoutheight=210mm,
  layouthoffset=5mm,
  layoutvoffset=5mm,
  margin=5mm,
  nohead,
  nofoot,
  nomarginpar,
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This frame goes out of this document.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel so stupid... Sorry about that, and thank you for your time. By the way, what is the advantages of the crop package over the geometry options layoutwidth... ?

Comment: @tobiasBora I see no big advantage of using `crop` since when `geometry` added support for “layouts”. But `crop` supports annotations and different crop marks, so in some cases it can be better.